# TDD in Rails: Failure/Error: visit login_url undefined local variable or method 'login_url'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd, factory-bot

I am following Ryan Bate's Railscast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test?view=asciicast) for TDD.

I implemented his password recovery from another video and now I am going back to learn testing.

I keep running into this failure when I run rspec:

```
 Failure/Error: visit login_url
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `login_url' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0xa7689f0>
```

I have tried searching for this error and I checked my routes to make sure a login_url or login_path exists. I am stumped and any hints would be appreciated

**How do I fix the undefined local variable or method 'login_url' error?**

Let me know if you need any additional files.

/spec/requests/password_resets_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe "PasswordResets" do
  it "emails user when requesting password reset" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    visit login_url
    click_link "password"
    fill_in "Email", :with => user.email
    click_button "Reset Password"
  end
end
```

/spec/factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence :email do |n|
      "foo#{n}@example.com"
    end
  name "huy"
  password "secret"
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
match '/login', :to => 'sessions#new'
```

Comment: Does login_url work in your app?

Comment: Let us see your spec_helper file: do you have capybara included?

Comment: @apneadiving I figured out what was going on. I had a browser check (to redirect IE users to another page) that was throwing things off. Thanks for the help :)